# Google / Bing Maps Show All Cities

Tags: javascript, google-maps, bing-maps

Trying to find a way without zooming in real close to tell Google or Bing maps to show all cities. Bing does a good job for the most part but still when you zoom in it shows a whole different set of cities.

I have a large monitor this map is going to be sitting on and really need it to show more than just the cities it shows on for example zoom level 8 or 9 on Google. Right now I load in roughly 2900 different locations and mark them on the map so I am trying to do it via the API no just going to maps.google.com

Has anyone come up against this issue and found a fix? Did some searching here as well on Google and maybe looking it up wrong but haven't found anyone looking for something like this.

Comment: really not clear what your problem is or what your expectations are. try different tile sets , there are lots of different providers and some have options as well

Comment: Did you go to level 8 or 9 on Google maps then zoom in one more level? You will see it shows a completely different set of cities. I dont want to have to stay zoomed in all the time I am trying to find a way to be zoomed out at the 8/9 levels and see all the cities.

Comment: but that is determined by the tiles that are delivered at different zoom levels. Look for different tile sets

Comment: Ok so your "answer" is its not possible correct? Would be easier to just say that. I dont want to have to zoom in then zoom out non stop would like to just stay zoomed out and still see all the cities.

Was trying to avoid having to buy a mapping software but looking like thats the route I have to go. Unless anyone else has ideas.

Comment: didn't say not possible. Have you tried looking for other tile sets and tile options?

Comment: Sorry misunderstood you, didn't know there was such thing as tile sets that one could use. Thought you were meaning different software. I will do some research on tile sets and see if I can find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldnt find either enough information to get "mapType" to work how I was wanting or it just doesnt do it. The goal was to be at lets say a zoom level of 8 and see every city in the US. I couldnt get any of the suggestions to do that.

Here is what I found that allowed me to do it my self though: 
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/

Basically I put in a transparent marker so it didnt show up then put info boxes with the names. This actually worked really well for me because I can zoom out 100% and still see all the names. Although at that level they would be overlapping being able to zoom in and out a few ticks and still see everything is great.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do that by using the Image Map Type API by implementing the mapType interface. Please refer to this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#ImageMapTypes) and implement the code in the way given in the example, replacing details with your specifications.

Hope this will help!!